# How to order elements in INIT in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, here you go guys.

I am learning Angular and wondering how to order items (array of strings). I know that there are different ways using controller etc, but I am just starting to learn it from today.

Was wondering if there is a way to orderBy on names? I know orderBy can be applied to a property name in array of objects if we have, but placing it in ng-repeat.

But how to achieve it in my code below?

**EDIT:**  I need the orderby both on initial display on page load, as well as when the user types something in the textbox when it filters.

```
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-init="names=['Sita','Ram', 'Amit','Cat','Boushick' ] ">
    <input type="text" name="txtName" data-ng-model="typedName" />
    <br />
    Typed Name is: {{ typedName }}
    <br />
    Names:
    <ul |orderBy:'names' >
        <li data-ng-repeat="personName in names | filter:typedName "> {{ personName | uppercase}}

        </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using `ng-Init` wrong.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/.  as the angular documentation states, use a controller instead, and sort the array there.

Comment: @Claies: Sorry that was my first job to refer that and then googling, but none satiated my scenario. I want it the way how I asked it.

Comment: the fact that you want it ordered on page load doesn't change the fact that you are using `ng-Init` incorrectly.  `ng-Init` **is not** a page initialization directive, despite it's name.  the angular documentation clearly states: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.", **in red**.  If you are having trouble ordering your data after initializing it in a controller, ask again. :)

Comment: @Claies: Well I achieved it through SQURD's help. Also, I like to tell you that I am watching a video, which is wonderful by Dan, he is explaining in same way as I wrote. Then only I tried it in my VS. See for yourself @ 16.32 time in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: It *may* work, but it is not the correct usage, and unexpected, hard to debug issues have been known to occur from the incorrect usage of this directive.

Comment: @Claies: Thank you, just I am learning, however, I would really listen to your good suggestions and I will ensure I will not code in that way using init like above, when I start on project :) Just I started of with this above youtube video.... Interestign and simple one..Until Modules *Confused*

Comment: keep in mind, that video is 2 years old, many things in angular have changed since it was produced.

Comment: @Claies: Thank you, oh I never noticed that :( Anyway I thought of getting some good videos, never realized the time video uploaded/made :( THanks again for cautioning me, but I guess its good to start with that video, he explains well especially for people like me who understands slowly :) :) I will then move on to other links and videos that are more recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `orderBy:'toString()'` before filter :)

```
<li data-ng-repeat="personName in names | orderBy:'toString()'|filter:typedName "> {{ personName | uppercase}}
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX0pwO2pvIvyMpWtvnUZ?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, worked like charm for both scenarios (Initial load as well as on filter). Amazed :) Thank you very much, and I liked it the way you smiled and explained :) :) I guess you must be very knowledgeable experienced old guy who is so humble and kind? (Don't know, one of my client was like that, the Russian guy :) ) Back to the point, I tried it using after filter, it worked too. Any difference?

Comment: Sorry dear i m just  21.But ya I love to reply with great smile :).And there is no difference in applying it before or after . :)

Comment: Lovely thank you. Unbelievable, you inspire me. I am 30 :( Damn! Still newbie to programming. Hope I learn with time.

Comment: Hey Don't worry you will learn soon.I also just started angular 4 months back :). The best resource is http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info

Comment: Lovely, thank you very much and thanks for your kind words :) I will go through this link you gave after I go through the video I am watching now :) :) Have a good time :) :) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

yes use `orderBy` as ,

```
<li data-ng-repeat="personName in names | orderBy:personName | filter:typedName "> ...
```

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/77aATo45MOj7WmDx6F5V?p=preview)

Comment: check the plunker and compare with your one i just added `| orderBy:personName` part only

Comment: K.Toress, I am very sorry, it did work now. I was trying to use " ' " as in the video. It didn't work. When I removed that " ' " it did work. I mean I used orderBy:'personName' where it didn't worked. Thank you very much for your time, sorry again for being silly